# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2017 Instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a website which works just fine with VS2017 and SQL Server 2012, 2014 and 2016. Today, I decided to upgrade the database to SQL Server 2017.

I installed SQL Server 2017 Express edition on the test server as a named instance (`SQLEXPRESS`). Then, I changed the connection string in `web.config` to the new named instance and I am receiving the following error:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +1385

This is what I tried so far:

1. Created an UDL file on web server and tried to connect to the named instance on the database server. *Test connection succeeded*
2. From SQL Server 2014 Management Studio on the web server, tried to connect to the named instance on the database server. *No issues with connecting and retrieving data from the SQL Server 2017 database.*
3. Installed SQL Server 2017 Management Studio on the web server to see if that resolves the issue but nothing changed. I still get the **Access denied** message

I am not sure what else needs to be done. Just wondering if anyone has tried upgrading their database to SQL Server 2017 without any issues?

Comment: The subject is a bit misleading here. The upgrade worked, but your connection is failing. The first part of the error is a very likely candidate: `Access is denied`. Then, after you get a could not be found. Are you running both instances on the same server? What bout the web service? Do you have named pipes enabled? TCP/IP? Are you providing the Instance name as part of the connection string? What errors are in the SQL Server's logs?

Comment: >>>What errors are in the SQL Server's logs?<<< There cannot be errors in error log because server was not found at all

Comment: Learning Savvy, so did you upgrade an existing instance or just made a new installation?

Comment: Do you connect locally or remotely? Your error means or the server is not running or it cannot be reached, So please make sure that: 1. server is running. 2. you use correct instance name and SQL Server browser is running 3. your firewall permits you to connect

Comment: @sepupic Correct, the server could not be found, however, if the Server is running, it may still have errors in there for other problems. Most likely, however, I image the OP isn't provide the Instance name, or TCP/IP and/or Named Pipes isn't enabled. of course, this is a lot of guess work at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I have named pipes enabled. Both versions are running side by side. No errors in SQL logs. Yes, instance name is provided as a part of connection string.

Comment: @sepupic I installed a fresh version of SQL 2017 alongside SQL 2016.

Comment: >>>instance name is provided as a part of connection string<<< You could provide incorrect instance name, besides, id SQL Server Browser running? If not, your server cannot be reached until you provide corrent port/pipe name (that is what Browser does)

Comment: When you tried the connection with the UDL and SSMS, did you use named pipes? Perhaps you should first alter your connection string to use TCP/IP

Comment: If your the instances are running on the same server, which port is the new instance running on? Have you tried passing the port instead? I.e. `YourServerName:11433` (assumed running on port 11433).

Comment: @Larnu If he'll pass 1433 he will connect to the default instance. So if he wants to connect to his named instance by indicating the port, he should know its port, and definitely should not pass in 1433

Comment: @sepupic 1433 <> **1**1433... *Edit: Passing Port **1**1433 will not connect you to a default instance running on port 1433 (as they are, unsurprisingly) different ports.*

Comment: I had to reinstall SQL 2017 and stop the SQL 2016 services. It is still not a named instance/side-by-side installation of SQL Server. But, now am able to access SQL 2017 from my .NET application without errors. At least it solves my problem for now. Thanks everyone for your replies.